# Include resource scopes in audience for IdentityServer3?

Tags: identityserver3

I'm trying to use the standard AuthenticationBuilder extension method AddJwtBearer on some new ASP.NET Core web apis that still get bearer tokens created by IdentityServer3.  I think my best bet for validating the resource access to the api (required scope in id server3) would be to make sure that I can get the scope value added to the audience like it does in identityserver4, or else add some validation for the scope claim in the config for the AddJwtBearer method if that's possible (looked but didn't see anything).

Is there a way in IdentityServer3 to make the audience of an access token an array and get any resource scopes added to it so that the token validation with just authority and audience will work now with idsrv3 tokens and continue to work cleanly when we upgrade to idsrv4?

Answer (score 2):

This is what solved my issue.  The tests on the identityserver GitHub site were awesomely helpful.

I needed to set LegacyAudienceValidation to true:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/CrossVersionIntegrationTests/blob/master/src/CoreApiIdSrv3/Startup.cs#L32

And then add explicit scope validation with the new ASP.NET Core policy system:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/CrossVersionIntegrationTests/blob/master/src/CoreApiIdSrv3/Startup.cs#L16

As background, in IS3 they didn't put the api name in the audience, but only in the scopes collection. In IS4 they put the api name in the audience and the api scopes (which may or may not be the same as the api name) in the scopes.